# Dax count formula based on multiple conditions met

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, measure

[image]Trying to create a count measure that gives me the number of times a person created a data point on a specific day, but not how many instances on that day.
so in the dataset below, looking for a count function that shows how many times Person A Appears on Tuesday, but only counts 1 per date. in the given data set the answer should be Tuesday = 2 for person A
and Wednesday = 4 for person A

I have Tried just about every COUNT function but just ant get one to use both conditions (person ID and unique day based on date)

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this with measure

```
Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[Person], Data[Day]))
```

[image]